# Translating C# regex into Powershell

Tags: c#, regex, powershell, escaping

I have this regex that works fine on C#:

```
\s*use\s+(.*?)([\r]{0,1}\n)
```

I have tried using it (or similar versions of it) on Powershell but it doesn't work.
Can someone help me ?

Some failed attempts:

```
$query = [regex]::Replace($query, "\s*use\s+(.*?)([`r]{0,1}`n)", ("USE [" + $database + "]"), [System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::IgnoreCase -bor [System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::Multiline)

$query = [regex]::Replace($query, "\s*use\s+([^`r]{1,}?)([`r])", ("USE [" + $database + "]$2"), [System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::IgnoreCase -bor [System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::Multiline)

$query = $query -ireplace "\s*use\s+(.+)([\r]{0,1})", ("USE [" + $database + "]"
```

Some questions:

1. Do I need to use `` `r`n `` to get C#'s `\r\n` ??? (I am not yet familiar with PowerShell...)
2. Since my 1st attempt seems to be using a .NET function, shouldn't this function work as it works on .NET? (because I think I see some differences but I can't pinpoint the cause - is it because of the escape characters?)
3. How is my first regex (presented above) translated into Powershell (either with [regex]::Replace() or with -ireplace)?

**UPDATE**

Data to test against (I use it to change the default DB in SQL scripts):

```
            CREATE LOGIN [test] WITH PASSWORD=N'j-9sfjhpsojhp', 
            DEFAULT_DATABASE=[test], DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[us_english], 
            CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=ON
            GO

            USE test
            GO

            /****** Object:  User [test]    Script Date: 10/07/2011 16:39:48 ******/
            GO

            CREATE USER [test] FOR LOGIN [test] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
            GO
```

Using a C# tool I get the `USE` line correctly (and I can replace it using sth like this : `$2USE NewDb$2`).

When using this (that uses the same regex) in Powershell, it doesn't work (I still get the `USE test` printed):

```
$database = "NewDb"
$query = Get-Content '<path to sql file>'
$query = [regex]::Replace($query, '\s*use\s+(.*?)([`r]{0,1}`n)', ("USE [" + $database + "]"), [System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::IgnoreCase -bor [System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::Multiline)
$query
```

**UPDATE**

A working solution:

```
$database = "NewDb"
$query = (Get-Content '<file path>') -join "`r`n"
$query = [regex]::Replace($query, '^\s*use\s+(.*?)$', ("`nUSE [" + $database + "]`n"), [System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::IgnoreCase -bor [System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::Multiline)
$query
```

However, newlines still don't work as in the .NET version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it work if you single quote the regex?  In Powershell, best practice is to single quote string literals, and only use double quotes if you explicitly want an expandable string.

Edit:

Okay, first you need to realize that Get-Content is going to return an array of strings (one per line), not a single multiline string. -Replace will still work on the array, but you don't want to match on the newlines - there aren't any.

```
$query_data = @'
CREATE LOGIN [test] WITH PASSWORD=N'j-9sfjhpsojhp', 
DEFAULT_DATABASE=[test], DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[us_english], 
CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=ON
GO

USE test
GO

/****** Object:  User [test]    Script Date: 10/07/2011 16:39:48 ******/
GO

CREATE USER [test] FOR LOGIN [test] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
GO
'@
$query_data | set-content ./query.txt

$database = "NewDb"
$query = Get-Content ./query.txt
$query = $query -replace '^\s*use\s+(.+)',"USE $database"
$query
```

Produces:

```
CREATE LOGIN [test] WITH PASSWORD=N'j-9sfjhpsojhp', 
DEFAULT_DATABASE=[test], DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[us_english], 
CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=ON
GO

USE NewDb
GO

/****** Object:  User [test]    Script Date: 10/07/2011 16:39:48 ******/
GO

CREATE USER [test] FOR LOGIN [test] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
GO
```

You can reduce the code to:

```
$database = "NewDb"
$query = (Get-Content '<path to sql file>') -replace '^\s*use\s+(.+)',"USE $database"
```

Comment: Nope! I have  now tried single quotes with Powershell escaping and then with C# escaping and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Can you post a sample of the data it's being used against, the results you're getting and the results you expected?

Comment: Thanks! By merging the file lines and modifying the regex a bit, I got it working (I post the final code above). However, I wonder why it has a problem with escape characters like `\r\n` (It still doesn't work with them even when I merge the lines with `-join "\r\n"` -- with quotes instead of slashes).

Comment: Return and newline are escaped in Powershell  as "`r`n" (backtick is the escape). In regex it's "\r" and "\n", so you need to join with "`r`n" and then match on "\r\n" in the regex.

Comment: Thanks. That clears things up! I should have thought of that (I was using backtick instead of backslash in my regex). :)